# Find $\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)^n\times \cos(n\theta)$ when $\cos(\theta)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $\cos(\theta)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Find the value, in terms of $a$ and $b$, of $\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)^n\times\cos(n\theta)$.

Consider that $n$ is of order $10^{18}$, hence, the answer in the form of summation of series (running from $i\in[0,10^{18}]$) is not computationally sound.

Comment: Are you certain that the answer doesn't involve/include series?

Comment: No, but I was hoping that there might exist some other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use complex analysis, then it can be extremely simple to solve. Consider $a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$. Its modulus is $\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$ and its argument is $\theta$. So your answer is real part of $\left(a+bi\right)^{n}$.

Let's compute specifically. By Binomial theorem, $\left(a+bi\right)^{n}$ can be expressed as $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {}_{n}C_{k} a^{n-k}(bi)^{k}$. So when k is even, you get real parts of $\left(a+bi\right)^{n}$. Using the fact that $i^{2}=-1$, real part of this summation can be simplified as $\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)\right\rfloor} {}_{n}C_{2k}a^{n-2k}\left(-b^{2}\right)^{k}$.

Comment: Very clever, I like it. +1